# C# stored procedure not inserting all data into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a small app where the user can insert data from textbox into SQL Server tables using stored procedures. When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it insert all data passed in the parameters, but when I try to store data from C#, the stored procedures don't insert all data - but there is no error thrown.

The stored procedure code is this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[insertpatient]
    @name varchar(50) = null,
    @surname varchar (50) = null,
    @placeb varchar (200) = null,
    @adress varchar(100) = null,
    @nrid varchar  (50) = null,
    @birthdt varchar (100) =null,
    @statut varchar(50) = null,
    @gender varchar(50) = null,
    @sympt varchar(max) = null,
    @ta varchar(50) =null,
    @t varchar(50) = null,
    @glikemy varchar(50) = null,
    @diagnosis varchar(200) = null,
    @terapy varchar(max) = null,
    @note varchar(max) = null,
    @date datetime = null,
    @other varchar (50) = null,
    @report varchar (max) = null
as
begin
    insert into tbl_pacientet (Name, Surnamei, BirthP, Adress, NrID, Birthdate,
                               Statut, Gender, Symptoms, TA, T, Glikemy, Diagnosis,
                               Terapy, Note, Date, Other, Report)
    values (@name, @surname, @placeb, @adress, @nrid, @birthdt,
            @statut, @gender, @sympt, @ta, @t, @glikemy, @diagnosis,
            @terapy, @note, @date, @other, @report)
end
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = medsoft; Integrated Security = true");

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertpatient", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtemri.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtmbiemri.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placeb", txtvendlindja.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", txtadresa.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nrid", txtpersonal.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdt", txtdite.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statut", cmbstatut.SelectedText);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sympt", txtsympt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta", txtta.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", txtt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@glikemy", txtglikemy.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diagnosis", txtdiagno.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terapiy", txtterapy.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", txtshenime.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", txtother.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", txtreport.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Could someone help me, and tell why the data are not being inserting all from textboxes to SQL Server tables, just some of them. Also there isn't any exception error. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: remove the ``i`` in ``terapiy`` for the line ``cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terapiy", txtterapy.Text);``

Comment: I removed , again is the same problem. No error throwed , but again not all data inserted

Comment: Giving default values (like `@name varchar(50) = null`) to your stored proc allows issues like this to happen.  If you intend to call it with all parameters it shouldn't have defaults.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Zer0 , I tried your advice, again the same problem.

Comment: Worst case, you can run a TRACE on the server to see what exact command is being ran.  Or debug your application and see the values of each parameter.  But I strongly agree with @marc_s that you should be usinig `.Add(...).Value = ` and _not_ `.AddWithValue(...)`.  The problems with the latter include type inference, among others.

Comment: Try "exec insertpatient @name,@surname, ... , @report"

Comment: Are any columns primary keys?  SQL server will allow only one row for each primary key.  ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer indicating the number of row modified.  So in c# check to make sure the number of rows are correct : int rowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: By "not all data inserted", do you mean some rows are missing or that some column values are NULL/empty? All of the parameter types on both client and proc are string/varchar so there will not be a conversion error unless the table column data types are not all varchar too. I suspect some of the column types are not varchar and the value can't be converted but your exception handling code isn't working properly.

Comment: @DanGuzman On the client side (C#) all strings are UTF-16 formatted Unicode. If there are international/scientific characters in the mix it might well be a collation/conversion (to varchar) issue.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, true but the symptom will be character loss rather than no data inserted.

Comment: @DanGuzman some coulmns value are empty

Comment: @user9290729, are the column types all varchar, matching the parameter types?

Comment: @DanGuzman all columns are varchar except date which is datetime. When I run the stored procedure in management studio (it work fine), just when I want to save data from c# form it doesn't save all columns. No error is throwed